# Insertion Query Not Working

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have a problem in which I think the INSERT statement is wrong as I keep getting the "SQL ERROR". Every time I do the UPDATE statement, it works just fine. I can't seem to find what's wrong with the query.

My database table: **emenu_user** HAS variables *id,username,password,email,contact and food*. ALL in which are **VARCHAR** (for now).

```
 public void Connection(){

        try{
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emenu?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","");
        if(connection!=null){
        System.out.println("Database connected");
        }else {System.out.println("Database NOT connected");}


        String name=username_field.getText();
        String pass=password_field.getText();
        String email=email_field.getText();
        String contact=contact_field.getText();

        String query="INSERT INTO emenu_user (username,password,email,contact) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setString(1,name);
        statement.setString(2,pass);
        statement.setString(3,email);
        statement.setString(4,contact);


        int set=statement.executeUpdate();

        if(set>0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved");
            homepageMenu homepageMenu= new homepageMenu();
            homepageMenu.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR");
        }


    } catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SQL FAILED");
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a more specific error message?

Comment: Is your id field auto-generating or auto-increment?

Comment: unfortunately no, the only output i get is build successfull and the SQL ERROR message. id field is auto increment @Thilo

Comment: Can you post the literal SQL Error?

Comment: Try to print the error , like `e.printStackTrace()` .

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'food' doesn't have a default value @Berger

Comment: Is `food` a `not null` field?

Comment: Try setting a default value for food?

Comment: OMG, my mistake. I kept focusing on the query, i didnt realise that food is not null. Thanks @Codeer and others . Problem Solved.

Comment: int set=statement.execute();
have you tried this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either set field `food` to `null`

```
ALTER TABLE `emenu_user` ALTER `food` SET DEFAULT NULL
```

or supply some value while insertion

```
String query="INSERT INTO emenu_user (username,password,email,contact, food) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    statement.setString(1,name);
    statement.setString(2,pass);
    statement.setString(3,email);
    statement.setString(4,contact);
    statement.setString(5,[SOME_VALUE]);
```

Comment: yeah, i just realised that. Thanks so much